# How to use table as variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is this query that I keep using over and over:

```
SELECT column_name, count(column_name) FROM table_name GROUP by column_name ORDER BY COUNT(column_name) DESC
```

I use this to check which different values there are in a column and how often they occur.
Because I use this query so often and it's repeating the same 4 times: column_name, I was like: why not make a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE countcv @table_name VARCHAR(50),@column_name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @column_name,COUNT(@column_name) FROM @table_name GROUP BY @column_name ORDER BY COUNT(@column_name)
END
```

Here is where I get stuck, I can not manage to get a variable tablename:

> Must declare the table variable "@table_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it directly. You need to use dynamicSQL approach. Assuming you pass correct table and column names. Below one should work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE countcv @table_name VARCHAR(50),@column_name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)  
set @SQL  = 'SELECT '+@column_name+',COUNT('+@column_name+') 
             FROM '+@table_name+'  
             GROUP BY '+@column_name+' 
             ORDER BY COUNT('+@column_name+')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that @Julien Vavasseur and @Dark Knight  has already addressed to your question.
However, I would like to add here that, Sql Server 2008 introduced [Table-Valued Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) by using which we can pass table type variable to the stored procedures. e.g.

Assuming you have a table by the name **tblTest** with the below columns

> ```
> ID  INT,
> Name VARCHAR(50)
> ```

**Step 1: Declare a new table User Defined Type**

```
CREATE TYPE tblTestType AS TABLE
(
    ID  INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

**Step 2: Create a STORED PROCEDURE that has tblTestType as parameter**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE countcv
(
    @tblName tblTestType readonly
)

AS
INSERT INTO tblTest (ID, Name)
SELECT ID, Name
FROM 
@tblName;
```

Then you can use DataTable (if you are using C#) and pass this data table as a parameter to the Stored Procedure.(you can find an example in the link I provided).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like this, you must use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE countcv @table_name sysname, @column_name sysname
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    Set @sql = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name)+', COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(@column_name)+') 
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)+' 
        GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name)+' ORDER BY COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(@column_name)+')'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

- Use sysname for data type for column and table names (buitin datatype for object names, alias to nvarchar(128))
- Use QUOTENAME to add delimeter to column and table names